# Iterate over a list of tuples and use them as params to a method

Tags: kdb

I have a list of tuples...

```
list1
list2

tuples: flip(list1; list2)
```

which I now want to iterate over to use the left and right of the tuple as params to a method defined. Something like iterate over tuples to pass in left and right as params to...

```
some_method: {[param1, param2] ...
```

Update: the list 1 is made of strings and list 2 is made up of symbols

```
hello, `bye
test, `again
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately went with something like this...

```
{h(some method; read0 list1[x]; list2[x];)} each til count list1')
```

May not be exactly how people handle things typically in q but it's how I could reason the syntax. With the above, I could iterate over both lists with an index

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to use each-both `'` so you don't have to flip the lists. Have a look here https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/

Re-using the example of Cillian

```
q)f:{[param1;param2]0N!"param1 is ",string[param1]," and param2 is ",string param2;}
q)f'[1 2 3;2 4 6]
"param1 is 1 and param2 is 2"
"param1 is 2 and param2 is 4"
"param1 is 3 and param2 is 6"

// Verify that the results are the same
q)(f ./:flip(1 2 3;2 4 6))~f'[1 2 3;2 4 6]
"param1 is 1 and param2 is 2"
"param1 is 2 and param2 is 4"
"param1 is 3 and param2 is 6"
"param1 is 1 and param2 is 2"
"param1 is 2 and param2 is 4"
"param1 is 3 and param2 is 6"
1b
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I updated the post - I should have been more clear. List 1 is actually a list of strings and list of symbols. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You need apply (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#apply-index) and each right (`/:`):

```
q)f:{[param1;param2]0N!"param1 is ",string[param1]," and param2 is ",string param2;}
q)f ./:flip(1 2 3;2 4 6);
"param1 is 1 and param2 is 2"
"param1 is 2 and param2 is 4"
"param1 is 3 and param2 is 6"
```

More documentation on iterators here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/

Comment: I updated the post - I should have been more clear. List 1 is actually a list of strings and list of symbols. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE] Had to submit a new answer as I can't comment yet and there are too many edits happening on StackOverflow. The fact that your first list is a list of strings and the second one is a list of symbols doesn't change the way how you iterate over the input. The only thing that changes is how you deal with the different parameter types inside your function

My solution works with a slight modification inside f. Notice, I removed string[param1] as param1 is already a string

```
q)f:{[param1;param2]0N!"param1 is ",param1," and param2 is ",string param2;}
q)f'[("hello";"World");`one`two]
"param1 is hello and param2 is one"
"param1 is World and param2 is two"
```

If you can give a more concrete example of what you are actually trying to do, maybe we can help.

Comment: Thanks Alexander! Ultimately I went with what I posted which made more sense to me but I'll also try to understand the syntax you gave / test it out